# In Perl, what's the meaning of this code " has 'absolute_E' => (is => 'rw',default => sub {0} );"

Tags: perl

The following codes make me so confused, I can't find any related knlowledge about the syntax "has ,is ,default, lazy". Can anybody make a detailed explain for me, best wishes.

```
has 'absolute_E'             => (is => 'rw', default => sub {0} );
has 'retract_speed_mm_min'   => (is => 'lazy');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
has 'retract_speed_mm_min'   => (is => 'lazy');
```

Judging by this line, this is probably a [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo) class. To confirm this, have a look near the top of the file, and you should see something like `use Moo`.

Moo is an object-oriented framework for Perl. I'll assume you understand OO concepts.

Some historical background: Perl 5 has built-in OO capabilities, however it can get a little cumbersome at times. Then [Moose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose) came around as an improved way of OOP in Perl. But Moose was also quite heavy, with a compile-time cost, so Moo (and also Mouse just before it) came after that as something of a lighter-weight subset of Moose.

`has` is for defining attributes in your class.

```
has 'absolute_E' => ( is => 'rw', default => sub {0} );
```

This defines an attribute named `absolute_E`.

`is => 'rw'` means it is readable and writable, which means you can do this:

```
my $value = $obj->absolute_E; # gets the value
$obj->absolute_E($value);     # sets the value
```

When you instantiate the object, you can supply a value for the attribute:

```
my $obj = My::Class->new( absolute_E => 5 );
```

But if you don't supply anything then `absolute_E` is set to `0` by `default`.

---

This second attribute has a few more things:

```
has 'retract_speed_mm_min' => (is => 'lazy');
```

This is short form for:

```
has 'retract_speed_mm_min' => ( 
    is      => 'ro', 
    lazy    => 1, 
    builder => '_build_retract_speed_mm_min' 
);
```

This attribute is `readonly` which means you can't change its value after construction. But you can supply a value at construction as before.

The `builder` is another way of providing a default value. It requires the class to have a separate method named `_build_retract_speed_mm_min` that should return the default value.

`lazy` works with `builder`. It means that the attribute should not be set by the builder until it the attribute is used. The delay may be used because the builder depends on other attributes in order to build this attribute's value.

There's a lot more in Moo and Moose. I would suggest reading http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2014/07-object-oriented-perl.html and https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual and https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo.

Answer (score 0):

That code basically equals

```
has ('absolute_E', 'is', 'rw', 'default', sub {0} );
has ('retract_speed_mm_min', 'is', 'lazy');
```

And `has` looks like a user-defined subroutine.

[`=>`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) is almost the same as [`,`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator):

> The `=>` operator is a synonym for the comma except that it causes a word on its left to be interpreted as a string if it begins with a letter or underscore and is composed only of letters, digits and underscores.

Comment: `has` is likely from [Moose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose#SYNOPSIS) or a similar oo helper module.

Comment: @ysth It is very possible :-)